# Trying to add Google Maps in my flutter application and getting error with no explanation

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

I am studying with Flutter. I am trying to learn how to entagrate Google maps to my app. But i take a problem with no explanation. I added all things we need to do. Help me, thanks.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application
    android:label="mobile_app_learning"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCer************k" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapLearning extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapLearning({super.key});
  @override
  State<MapLearning> createState() => _MapLearningState();
}

class _MapLearningState extends State<MapLearning> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  final firstLocation = const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(38.7412482, 26.1844276), zoom: 10);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: firstLocation,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my codes to display map on the screen. When i am trying to debug my code its crashing with no error message.

```
C:\Users\hikme\Desktop\Flutter\mobile_app_learning\android>"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr/bin/java.exe"    "-Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew" -classpath "C:\Users\hikme\Desktop\Flutter\mobile_app_learning\android\\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain -q -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=C:\Users\hikme\Desktop\Flutter\mobile_app_learning\lib\main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application -Pdart-defines=Zmx1dHRlci5pbnNwZWN0b3Iuc3RydWN0dXJlZEVycm9ycz1mYWxzZQ==,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ==,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQ0FOVkFTS0lUX1VSTD1odHRwczovL3d3dy5nc3RhdGljLmNvbS9mbHV0dGVyLWNhbnZhc2tpdC9hNzk0Y2YyNjgxYzZjOWZlN2IyNjBlMGU4NGRlOTYyOThkYzljMThiLw== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug 
C:\Users\hikme\Desktop\Flutter\mobile_app_learning\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
```

here is no explanation error message output. There is no message after de last word, Error:

[Here is my debug codes. I can't add image please tap to link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tHFl.png)

Comment: We can't see the error on your image. Also, please share your code/errors not as images but rather as `code block`

Comment: I can't see the error message either. I didn't write any code because app isn't debug itself.

Comment: @AppSolves i added new things to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Guys my project can't debug anymore i don't understand anything about it. Always getting same error and crashing.

Comment: Hello, you should show what the console says when you run your code so that the community can help you better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem.

```
     flutter clean
     flutter run
```

-> then app crashed. I added the console error.
[Here is the message after flutter run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Gzh.png)

Comment: Then follow what the error tells you to do to fix it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes i did flutter clean and flutter run then problem solved.